# EJS For loop and If statement are not displaying the right value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I'm building an application that will allow users to click on a button and when they return to the page, it will show a message saying "Already interested". When I display the page, it skips over the if statement in the for loop and displays the else statement. What am I doing wrong?

Below is my code and current output.

```
<% for(var i=0; i < userInterests.length; i++) { %>
   <% if ((username == userInterests[i].username)  && (postID == userInterests[i].post_id)){ %> 
      <p>Already interested</p>
      <% break; %> 
   <% } else { %> 
      <form action="/jobs/interested/<%= post._id %>" method='POST'>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">I'm interested</button>
      </form>
      <% break; %> 
   <% } %> 
<% } %>
```

[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tf4rq.png)

[MongoDB entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZGL4.png)

Comment: It does not like an issue with EJS. Otherwise, it would not have compiled. Try to log all the values in the `if` statement and see their values in the loop. That will give you a clear idea of why your `if` statement is evaluated as false.

Comment: For your logic to be more solid in js, consider using `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: I already logged their values and they match the entry in the database. Is there a problem with my code's logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logic issue , you are testing username and postID only with values of userInterests[0].username and serInterests[0].post_id because you have break; statement in your 2 conditions , Here is a solution for the issue :

```
<% var userInterested = false %> 
<% for(var i=0; i < userInterests.length; i++) { %>
   <% if ((username == userInterests[i].username)  && (postID == userInterests[i].post_id)){ %> 
          <% userInterested = true; %>
          <% break; %> 
   <% } %>
<% } %>
<% if (userInterested) { %> 
   <p>Already interested</p>
<% } else { %> 
   <form action="/jobs/interested/<%= post._id %>" method='POST'>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">I'm interested</button>
   </form>
<% } %>
```